# JISON: why in regexp used "." instead of \.?

Tags: regex, jison

From example on http://zaach.github.io/jison/docs/#specifying-a-language

```
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER';
```

why in this regexp used `"."` instead of `\.` ?

Comment: I'm assuming the double quotes means "literal", so `"."` is what you would expect for `\.`.

Comment: in normal regexp "." means "anything", what kind of regexp it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a Jison grammar tokenization rule not an exact regex.
In Jison a token is surrounded in `"`.

In the compiled rules you can see the rule converted to a regex:

```
["[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?\\b", "return 'NUMBER';"],
```

Comment: where I can read more about "Jison grammar tokenization rule"?